# Required column names in ssis package

Tags: ssis

In SSIS package input date came from column headers is col1,col2,col3,col4 but actually the in the destination the col names are A, B, C, D. pls let me know what kind of transformation used?

Answer (score 0):

No transformation is required.

In the destination component (ADO.NET, OLE DB, or ODBC Destination), after specifying the connection manager and the table name, the Columns tab will list all the columns in the data flow (col1, col2, col3, etc) and the all the columns in the destination (A, B, C)

You will manually drag a connection between col1 to A, col2 to B, etc until you have mapped all the fields needed.